# run insert query after select query mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to  insert into multi table after select query return 0 (not found raws) select query working and insert query never done when submite "displayid" and there is no any syntax error

code:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["displayid"] == TRUE) {

        $sqlid  = "SELECT * FROM doc1 WHERE idnum ='$pidnum' AND stats='$ok'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlid);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $sqlup = "UPDATE doc1 SET  m_phone='$pm_phone', seen='$dataseen' WHERE  idnum ='$pidnum'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sqlup);
            $found = 1;
        } else {
            $found   = 0;
            $sqlfail = "INSERT INTO fail(fname,lname,tname,funame,idnum,m_phone,reg_date)
VALUES ('$pfname','$plname','$ptname','$pfuname','$pidnum','$pm_phone','$todaydate')";
            $conn->query($sqlfail)
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do some debug as echo the query `echo sqlfail;` and then copy paste the same on mysql directly, you may get some information if there is an error etc.

Comment: Use parameters for the query instead of concatenating the strings and you would avoid the problem you have here with missing quotes and the code will not be so insecure

Comment: provide full sql create statement and values for your params

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
  $sqlfail = "INSERT INTO  fail(fname,lname,tname,funame,idnum,m_phone,reg_date)
VALUES ('".$pfname."','".$plname."','".$ptname."','".$pfuname."','".$pidnum."','".$pm_phone."','".$todaydate."')";
```

make similar changes for update command as well

Comment: Color says some syntax error, BTW your intention will make no change.

Answer (score 1):

you actually have one error

```
$conn->query($sqlfail)
```

should be

```
$conn->query($sqlfail);
```

Comment: fixed this and still not inserted

Comment: provide full sql create statement and values for your params. Some debug need to be done there

Answer (score 0):

```
AND stats='$ok'";
```

i can't see a variable with this name i think you mean `AND stats='ok'";`